# В каких случаях может быть выброшено ConcurrentModificationException?

Tags: java, исключения

В каких случаях может быть выброшено ConcurrentModificationException?

Привидите пожалуйста примеры

Comment: `List<String> strings =...; for (String string : strings) strings.remove(string);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самый простой случай - удаление элемента из коллекции при обходе ее в цикле

```
List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
l1.add("1");
l1.add("2");
l1.add("3");

for (String s : l1) {
  if ("3".equals(s)) {
     l1.remove(s);
  }
}
```

здесь в момент вызова `l1.remove(s)` будет выброшено исключение `ConcurrentModificationException`. Тоже самое справедливо, если вы будете добавлять элементы в коллекцию во время обхода её в цикле.